# execute function with split() is not a function

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting this code Javascript.

> TypeError: colors.split is not a function

When I execute...

```
cars(infoCar.color); // this is String.

function cars(colors) {
  var car = colors.split(',');
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: `colors` is simply not a string. Check the type of the argument in the function.

Comment: `// this is String. // Nope`

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What do `console.log(colors, typeof colors);` etc. reveal?

Comment: sorry, this element is a ARRAY. deleted question pls.

Comment: Delete the question yourself by clicking on the _delete_ link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's not a string, as the code you wrote works:

```js
var infoCar = {
    color: "red,orange,blue"
}
cars(infoCar.color); // this is String.

function cars(colors) {
  var car = colors.split(',');
  console.log(car);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Please check data type of the colors like typeOf colors whether the string or 
some other data type likes array and object.

For example:

```js
    var infoCar = {
      color: ["red,green"]
     
    };   
    cars(infoCar.color); 
    function cars(colors) {
      /*var car = colors.split(','); //TypeError: colors.split is not a 
      function*/
      //correct code
      var car = colors[0].split(',');
      console.log(car);
    }
```